# What does it mean if a laptop has been erased but has a Certificate of Authenticity?

Tags: windows, license-key

I thinking about buying an HP 20-B013 All in One 20" on Ebay, but the description says

> This All In One is in very good condition.  The screen has no marks.  The hard drive was erased, so there is NO operating system loaded.  It does have a COA for Windows 8

I know nothing about computers, but I do understand that COA is the Certificate of Authenticity.

Does this mean I would be able to reinstall Windows 8 with because the COA is included?

Answer (score 2):

The COA is one of two pieces you need to reinstall Windows - the other piece is the installation media itself. If the computer comes with installation media (CD or DVD), you're okay. If not, it will be difficult to get media without effectively paying for a new license.

Comment: The COA is usually in the form of a sticker, and it has the product Key, if it is for Windows 8 then the media is fairly easy to get off the internet directly from MS...without buying a new license

Comment: @TheX That is not true. COAs for Windows 8 do not have a product key on them. That is only true for Windows 7 and back. The product keys for Windows 8 are slipstreamed in OEM discs or included on a product key card with a retail disc. He does need to buy a new license to get a working, legal key.

Comment: Really??? that is garbage!

Comment: Looks like the OEM keys are now embedded into the BIOS? if this is the case then any media should work..

Comment: @TheX If it's an OEM Windows 8 disc, you won't need to enter a key. If it's a retail disc, you'll need the little card that comes with the box that has the key on it. It was a silly change on Microsoft's part. I work in a business and now the OEM sticker is no longer enough to stay compliant. Such a hassle having to keep 1,000 Windows boxes on a shelf somewhere.

Comment: So you are saying that an OEM key will not work on a retail disc anymore?

Comment: @TheX If you have the OEM key, a retail disc should work. My point was that he doesn't have it, so in order to install from any media he would need to obtain one first.

Comment: I understand that I was just making sure I understood correctly...